# Codeigniter issue php,fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fetch

I made a program in php and it works properly. Now, i wanna make that program using Codeigniter.

Here is my old program:

```
    <?php include('connect.php');

?>

<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
    <body>

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">



    <a href="estudiante.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">AGREGAR</button></a><br /><br />
        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>

    <?php

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT s.*, c.nombre AS carrera FROM materias s LEFT JOIN carreras c ON s.carrera_id=c.id");//ESTA FUNCION ME AYUDA A ACOMODAR LAS CARRERAS EN LA COLUMNA "CARRERA" DE LA TABLA
                $i=1;
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        echo "<tr>
                                <td>".$i."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carrera']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['nombre']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['descripcion']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['carga_horaria']."</td>
                                <td align='center'>
                                    <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                                    <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$row['id']."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>";
                        $i++;

                    }
                ?>


            </table>    

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

And, "connect.php" file

```
    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root')OR die('error : '.mysql_error());
    $db=mysql_select_db('desafio');

    if($db){
        echo '';

    }else{
        echo 'Error :' .mysql_error(); 
    }


?>
```

This is my Codeigniter code:

My "view" file:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>


    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2 align="center">TABLA:MATERIAS</h2>
        <input id="busqueda_tabla" type="text">
            <table class="table table-hover" align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" id="tabla_busqueda">
                <thead>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Carrera</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Carga horaria (hs)</th>
                    <th>Accion</th>
                </thead>


    <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($records as $record) {

            echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$i."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carrera."</td>
                      <td>".$record->nombre."</td>
                      <td>".$record->descripcion."</td>
                      <td>".$record->carga_horaria."</td>
                      <td align='center'>
                         <a href='editar.php?editar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>EDITAR</button></a> |
                         <a href='borrar.php?borrar=1&iden=".$record->id."'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>BORRAR</button></a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    ?>
    </table>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my Crudmodel file:

```
      <?php

    Class Crudmodel extends CI_Model{

        public function getRecords(){

            $this->db->select('s.*, c.nombre AS carrera')
                     ->from('materias s')
                     ->join('carreras c', 's.carrera_id = c.id', 'left');
            $q = $this->db->get();

            if($q -> num_rows() > 0){

                return $q->result();
            }

            return false;

        }

    }


?>
```

And the controller file:

```
    <?php

    class Home extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $this->load->model('Crudmodel');
            $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();
            $this->load->view('home', $data['records']);

        }
    }
?>
```

But it does not work, i got this errors:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/607303edcd861d0a2257611c925f3e6e.png
https://i.gyazo.com/eb9d833bf5d0818db2906ec1447550c0.png
https://i.gyazo.com/c5bb77d50315888a375a1e775a5ad68c.png
```

Dont know what to do :/

Comment: Database not working properly. Please check your application>config>database.php file

Answer (score 0):

The main cause is database connection. First of all, check your database connection in database.php file. If all thing is good then please load your database. 
You can load database by two ways:

> 1. In autoload file: autoload library > pass database in the array.
> 2. Or in model, please load in Constructor :  $this->load->db

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('Crudmodel');
        $data['records'] = $this->Crudmodel->getRecords();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }
}
```

The loading of the database in codeigniter

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '****',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => TRUE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array()
);
```

And then autoload it. It is also good to autoload some libraries and helpers also. Read the manual fully.

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Some good reading here also

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

And

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views